# Is language conditional in some operations?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app where I use the Geocoder to get a place's coordinates.

The operative is this:

- The user defines an address.
- The geocoder finds that address and I get the coordinates from that address.
- This coordinates are in decimal format and I need them in degrees-minutos so I format them.

To format the coordinates from decimal to degrees-minutes I use:

```
String frmtLatitude = Location.convert(Double.parseDouble(lat), Location.FORMAT_MINUTES);
```

So, if I have for example this latitude `43.249591` in decimal value, it returns it like this `43:14.97546`.

After this, I have to make some operations to finally get the latitude with this appearance: `4314.975`

When I do this operations, one of them is to split the value using the ".". I split `14.97546` to get in one hand the `14` and in the other `97546`.

Until here, everything ok. It works fine when I have my phone's language selected to be in english. But if I select to be in spanish, the app crashes. I have followed the stacktrace and it points there. Is like that in english when using the first commented function to convert from decimal to degrees-minutes it separates the decimals with a "." but if I have it in spanish, it separates them with a ",".

Can this really happen or the cause could be another thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at the source code of the `convert` method

```
public static String convert(double coordinate, int outputType) {
    if (coordinate < -180.0 || coordinate > 180.0 ||
        Double.isNaN(coordinate)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("coordinate=" + coordinate);
    }
    if ((outputType != FORMAT_DEGREES) &&
        (outputType != FORMAT_MINUTES) &&
        (outputType != FORMAT_SECONDS)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("outputType=" + outputType);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Handle negative values
    if (coordinate < 0) {
        sb.append('-');
        coordinate = -coordinate;
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");
    if (outputType == FORMAT_MINUTES || outputType == FORMAT_SECONDS) {
        int degrees = (int) Math.floor(coordinate);
        sb.append(degrees);
        sb.append(':');
        coordinate -= degrees;
        coordinate *= 60.0;
        if (outputType == FORMAT_SECONDS) {
            int minutes = (int) Math.floor(coordinate);
            sb.append(minutes);
            sb.append(':');
            coordinate -= minutes;
            coordinate *= 60.0;
        }
    }
    sb.append(df.format(coordinate));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

We can see that it uses a `DecimalFormat` with a given pattern. So, if we look to the DecimalFormat constructor :

```
public DecimalFormat(String pattern) {
    // Always applyPattern after the symbols are set
    this.symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
    applyPattern(pattern, false);
}
```

We can see here that even if we give a pattern, it uses the locale values. The javadoc also said :

> Parameters:
>
> **pattern** A non-localized pattern string.

To finish, we can go here to see the different local variant of numbers representation : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

So we can see that US-English use the "dot format" and that Spanish use "comma format".

To answer your question : the proflem you're facing is probably due to the Decimal format of your locale. I advice you to be REALLY CAREFUL when converting types of objects to make manipulation on them. Converting an int to a String should be only to display it.

I think you should seperate decimal part of your number when it stills a float (or any decimal type) and then convert your object to a String to display it. You can take a look at `Math` class or search SO to get some example on how to this ;)

Also, as @Dmitry said, you can get DecimalSeparator with `DecimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator()`.

**Sources**

[Location.convert(double,int) source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.1_r1/android/location/Location.java#Location.convert%28double%2Cint%29)

[DecimalFormat(String) source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#DecimalFormat.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29)

[Java "Decimal and thousands separators"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Comment: It is really detailed answer. Thank you for link to Oracle doc, it is quite useful. I didnt know that some languages use dot as group separator

Answer (score 1):

You are right, decimal seperator depends on your locale. You can get it by something like this

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    char separator = formatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator();
```

Comment: So, the final `separator` value would have a "." or a "," depending on my locale. How could I use it with the `.split()` method?

Comment: you can get separator by code above and of course you can use it in split() method